# Can I change the audio volume after play?

Tags: javascript, html

I can create an audio element, change its volume and play it.

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume):

```
var obj = document.createElement('audio');
console.log(obj.volume); // 1
obj.volume = 0.75;
```

Assuming I have a 10 second audio, **after starting** it, I would like to **change its volume**, is it possible?

Comment: yes, you can do that.

Comment: @dandavis can you show me how? :D

Comment: By setting its [`volume`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume) property. Do you mean you want the volume to change automatically after starting playback?

Comment: @showdev not necessarily automatically, assuming I change a slider like youtube / ubuntu for example (audio has already started)

Comment: [Video Volume Slider in HTML5 and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926221/video-volume-slider-in-html5-and-javascript) might be helpful.